# Find the impacts of alleles on the intensity of a disease

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, correlation, biostatistics, odds-ratio

I have a dataset, I attach a sample of my data and the code. I have one column which shows the intensity value of a disease, one column which shows that its weak of moderate and the other columns are different alleles! (in my real data I have 25 rows and 36 allels). So, I want to find the relation ship between the allels and the category of the disease. For example, the allele1 has an impact and if a row has allel1, the intensity is weak! ( i know that this is not easy). I searched a lot to find the best way, like logistic regression and odds value. However, I am not sure what is the best way for this? Could you please help me with you suggestion?

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['intensity'] = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
df['category'] = ['weak', 'moderate', 'moderate', 'extreme', 'extreme']
df['Allele1'] = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
df['Allele2'] = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
df['Allele3'] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
df['Allele4'] = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
df['Allele5'] = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
df['Allele6'] = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
df['Allele7'] = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
df['Allele8'] = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
df['Allele9'] = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
df
```

Comment: Are the rows individuals? Please explain. Then, 25 observations for 36 allells are simple to few ...

Comment: Yes. They are individuals.